# mono fails to serve css files [error] command failed: failed to send file (file data)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, apache, mono

I'm running mvc2 project on ubuntu 12.04.2 with mono  2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2) - i installed apache mod_mono_server4 ... 
Mono is no more serving css or script files, in the apache log the entry is:
 [error] command failed: failed to send file (file data)
 every time it serve a page.
I'm sure it has read/write permission into that folder - it serves correctly all pages but without css.
 Trying to access ccs directly apache says "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."
Any help on what i'm missing will be really welcome
Mi virtualHost file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName alibi.sr
ServerAdmin web-admin@alibi.sr
DocumentRoot /var/www/nopunti/alibi/alibi_WebUI
MonoServerPath alibi.sr "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
MonoDebug alibi.sr true
MonoSetEnv alibi.sr MONO_IOMAP=all
MonoApplications alibi.sr "/:/var/www/nopunti/alibi/alibi_WebUi"
<Location "/">
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
MonoSetServerAlias alibi.sr
SetHandler mono
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
</Location>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I recommend nginx, not apache

Comment: Finally i just copied all files into another directory, modified the virtual host, restarted apache and it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i just copied all files into another directory, modified the virtual host, restarted apache and it started working again.